# Improving performance of parallax effect triggered by mousemove event

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, css-transforms

I made a parallax effect [here](https://codepen.io/shampliu/pen/WOLOzG) inspired by [this website](http://www.etiennegodiard.com/). Currently it listens for mousemove events and uses CSS transforms to do the parallax. I also use lodash's throttle function so the event doesn't get fired as often.

*Pseudocode:*

```
let parallax = (e) => {
  // calculate deltas of mouse x and y from the midpoint
  // multiplier = 0.01
  // for every parallax image
  //   translate image (multiplier * dx, multiplier * dy)
  //   multiplier *= 0.8 
}
document.addEventListener('mousemove', _.throttle(parallax, 10));
```

However, the performance of this is still not optimal and I was wondering what I could do to improve it?

Increasing the throttle time results in very apparent lag. I was also looking into using canvas and requestAnimationFrame but I'm not sure how the performance of that stacks up against using CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have redone you parallax efect to use 3d positioning and perspective changes.

The perspective change simulates changing your point of view.

the objects should have a z position that makes them move relatively more or less, just as in the real world

It should run much more efficient now, since all this is handled in a single property change and executed on the GPU

```js
  let bg = document.querySelector('.background');
  let rect = bg.getBoundingClientRect();
  let midX = rect.left + rect.width / 2;
  let midY = rect.top + rect.height / 2;

let parallax = (e) => {

  let dx = e.clientX - midX;
  let dy = e.clientY - midY;

  let mult = -0.5;
  let perspective = `${dx * mult}px ${dy * mult}px`;
  bg.style.perspectiveOrigin = perspective;
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", parallax);
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  perspective: 500px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.one {
  top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translateZ(1px);
}

.two {
  top: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.text {
  line-height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="background" style="perspective-origin: -18.025px 14.15px;">
  <h1 class="plax text">Hello.</h1>
  <img class="plax two" src="http://www.etiennegodiard.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/YokaVendredi-copie-min.png">
  <img class="plax one" src="http://www.etiennegodiard.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Yokaombre5.png">
</div>
```